# Is it safe to mass replace legacy ASP tags with <?= ?>

Tags: php, regex, legacy

The current task is to migrate a big, old, hairy, poorly optimized wordpress site to a new host and web server. They want to upgrade their php version so they can launch a new e-commerce platform on their site. They're angry at their current hosts, for... some reason. Beats me.

Their site is old. Real old. They've decided against upgrading or overhauling, contrary to our advice, up until now. It's been a train wreck so far for a lot of reasons, but as far as we're concerned here, I just have one question about legacy php syntax.

I've come across a lot of ASP tags. I'm freshly graduated, and didn't even know these were a thing until a few weeks ago. A bunch of output is enclosed in these tags, and I was wondering if it might be as simple as a RegEx search replace.

```
FIND    | <%=?(.*)%>
REPLACE | <?= $1; ?>
```

Will that break anything? Were ASP tags used for anything other than a shorthand echo?

Comment: Use `<%=?(.*?)%>`, not `<%=?(.*)%>`

Comment: You cannot replace ASP tags with PHP tags. ASP and PHP are not the same languages.

Comment: @JayBlanchard According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php, in php the <% %> and <?= ?> do exactly the same thing, shorthand open echo close. Is this wrong? Did I misunderstand it?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Um, thanks, but could you re-open my question? It has nothing to do with how much my ReGex is matching, and isn't associated with the similar question at all.

Comment: Once you apply your regex against real text, you will see it is the essential part.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, I just want you to be sure that the code is PHP and not ASP.

Comment: So real question is about ASP vs PHP, why duplercate of a regex ? Use what syntax is valid for asp to match. Make sure it not like span liness `(?s)<%=?(.*?)%>`